# IP.Board hooks, where are they stored?

Tags: php, ipb

I finally broke down the other day and made the purchase of IP.Board to move my website over to a more professional looking forum software than MyBB. I feel like it was one of the biggest mistakes of my life. I'm not familliar with any of the programming style's that are used here and to me it's just a jumbled mess.

I've been staring at IP.Board for the last two days trying to figure out how to do things such as create simple hooks, etc, however the website guides are down and there's not any tutorials that I'm able to follow on the Internet that I can find.

**So, i decided to just view the source-code of the hooks that came with the forum software**, such as the recent posts, but it seems like I've made a massive mistake, upon opening the source file in the hooks/ directory I was presented with a few lines of code:

```
<?php
class boardIndexRecentTopics
{
    public $registry;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->registry = ipsRegistry::instance();
    }

    public function getOutput()
    {
        return $this->registry->getClass('class_forums')->hooks_recentTopics();
    }   
}
```

Now, I'm completely lost, and have nothing to reference and I keep digging, and digging, and digging for answers, but I can't find anything. I'm seriously just trying to figure out how to do basic things, like display the users avatar, create a link to a profile, etc.  I already know how to poll the database to get the information I need. I understand basic structure from working in Java for so long and I've had tons of PHP projects in the past that were perfectly funtional, but this is on a whole new level of confusing.

***Where can I find the actual source-code to this `recent topics` hook so I can start picking up on things.***

I would have been done 12 times over if I was using MyBB still which I'm completely familiar with.

Comment: I don't know ipb but from the code it is getting an object `class_forums` from the registry and running the `hooks_recentTopics` method of that object.  So somewhere that object is being added to the registry.  So find the code for that class.

Comment: @Abra - Alright will do, I'm not used to the use of classes within PHP, I've always used functions() for everything while passing parameters. So this is a completely new style for me. Thanks for the reply.